# What is a reasonable time to get a gps fix with 10 meters precision?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I hope I'm asking this at the right part of Stack Exchange. Please bear with me if I'm wrong.

I'm developing some gps based applications. The demands I have for precision are not very high, but I need to know the possible errors.

I have learned that the [fourth decimal gives you ~10 meters precision.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/8674#8674l) That should be enough for me.

The real question is how fast will I get that precision realiably in different environments (indoors, outdoors free sky, forest, cloudy, city etc).

The applications I'm developing is for handheld devices so I prefer to have the gps active in as short intervals as possible.

As I do now, the intervals I use the gps are more governed by battery life than precision. Now I'm trying to balance the two.

Comment: it is hard to say, as it really depends on the chip, the weather, the wall around you ... I would say my phone takes between a few seconds and no more than 30 seconds most of the time to have a similar precision.

Comment: Still there must be an approximate time on how long it will take on average. And what is reasonable to calculate on from a more general point of view.

Comment: Actually, there really doesn't have to be an approximate time for this, unless your definition of the word "approximate" encompasses well over an order of magnitude.  You should also be clear whether you're simply interested in a GPS fix, or a **location** fix.  GPS is just one of multiple techniques used, and especially if the other techniques are used, fix time can be reduced a lot.  But, it still depends on lots of factors, like the ones you mentioned, and also on things like how recently the device got a location fix (requested by the OS, or another app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't wait for some number of seconds and assume that that's enough to get a GPS fix. Instead, when you get locations from location manager, check the result of [`Location.getAccuracy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) and wait until that returns a number less than 10 meters.

Answer (score 3):

if you have good view (no major obstructions like high buildings) to sky, with A-GPS 20s, normal GPS 30-45 seconds.
If you have bad view, it can take much longer.
However you better check that the timestamp of the location is a recent one, (time  diff to current time is small) and that horicontal accuracy (Location.getAccuracy()) is not horrible:

check for < 20m, if you check for 10m you may loose many positions especially in the first minute.